# Microsoft Edge either won't start downloads or renames them to have no extension

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-edge

I have a fresh install of Windows 10, and while using Edge I've noticed two issues that are pretty annoying.

1. Automatic downloads won't start.  In the downloads list, the url is listed, but no data is ever received.  For example, from the Office 365 portal:

   [image]
2. Downloads initiated by a click get renamed so so that any .* extension becomes _*:

   [image]

Clicking 'Retry' allows the download to proceed, but then I have to rename the file.

What's causing these problems, and how do I correct them?

There are these two threads on the Microsoft Community forum for Windows:
[Can't download anything on Microsoft Edge!](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/apps_windows_10-msedge/cant-download-anything-on-microsoft-edge/6fcac990-4b24-4899-94dc-7e959f1dc116)

I tried those suggestions, and they didn't help me.  One of them was to change my temporary internet files location to be on the system drive using the "Internet Options".  My user profile is on D:, so I tried to move the files to C:\Users\Ben (not my user profile, just a directory I made), and it logged me off to "finish moving files", but when I logged back on the location was set back to the original location - so I'm not sure if that's something that I have to solve or not.

Answer (score 0):

After struggling with it for a while, I was able to get this solved by deleting the Edge package folder (`%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Packages\Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge_8wekyb3d8bbwe`) and then running the following command (as an admin):

```
Get-AppXPackage -AllUsers -Name Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge |% {Add-AppxPackage -DisableDevelopmentMode -Register "$($_.InstallLocation)\AppXManifest.xml" -Verbose}
```

Strangely enough, this wasn't the first time I had tried this, but it was the first time I had been able to completely delete the folder.  Directions were found here:

http://www.techtantri.com/how-to-reinstall-microsoft-edge-browser/